# Rails: Ajax local works fine, but 404 in nginx server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, nginx

in the js file :

```
function jqShowResourcesSelection( elem, select_id )
{
    if (elem.checked){
        $("#" + select_id).attr("disabled","disabled");
        $.ajax({
            url: '/testbeds/resources_selection',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType : 'script',
            data: {"configuration_id": $("#" + select_id).val()},
            success: function() {
                addFilter();
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        $("#testbed_configuration_id").attr("disabled", false);
        $("#ResourcesSelection").html('');
    }
}
```

In routes.rb

```
ResourceManager::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :testbeds do
    collection do
      post :resources_selection
    end
  end
  resources :resources
  resources :configurations

  ...................

  root :to => 'configurations#index'

end
```

It works fine in my local machine, both development and production environment. But in the server,  nginx, after trigger the js function, the chrome console will show:

```
POST http://example.com/testbeds/resources_selection 404 (Not Found)
```

I also tried the "post" to "get":

```
function jqShowResourcesSelection( elem, select_id )
{
    if (elem.checked){
        $("#" + select_id).attr("disabled","disabled");
        $.ajax({
            url: '/testbeds/resources_selection.js',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {"configuration_id": $("#" + select_id).val()},
            success: function() {
                addFilter();
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        $("#testbed_configuration_id").attr("disabled", false);
        $("#ResourcesSelection").html('');
    }
}
```

routes.rb:

```
ResourceManager::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :testbeds do
    collection do
      get :resources_selection
    end
  end
 ...........................

end
```

It also works fine in local no matter development or production environment. But still 404 in the server after I checked the checkbox.

And ngnix config as below:

```
http {
    passenger_root /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.18;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/bin/ruby;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name cth-infra-07.datadomain.com 10.110.131.4 localhost;
        root /var/www/webapps/;
        rack_env production;
        passenger_enabled on;
        passenger_base_uri /resource_manager;
        passenger_base_uri /request_handler;
        passenger_base_uri /scheduler;
        passenger_base_uri /resque;
        passenger_base_uri /central_server;
    }
```

Can some one help me about it ? Thanks.

Comment: It is not a Rails issue, your nginx is not configured properly

Comment: Can you tell me how to configure it ?

Comment: Hope this will help https://gist.github.com/shapeshed/1276230